# Need Grouping of Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I want to get regex for the following construct where it should result as:

> Actions 
>   and Sci-Fi

```
<a href="/?genre=Action">Actions</a> <a href="/?genre=Sci-Fi">Sci-Fi</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't parse html files with regex. If you insist then you could use the below regex and get the text inside anchor tags from group index 1.

```
<a\s[^<>]*>([^<>]*)<\/a>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aB2vZ7/4)

**Explanation:**

```
<a                       '<a'
\s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
[^<>]*                   any character except: '<', '>' (0 or more
                         times)
>                        '>'
(                        group and capture to \1:
  [^<>]*                   any character except: '<', '>' (0 or
                           more times)
)                        end of \1
<                        '<'
\/                       '/'
a>                       'a>'
```

Comment: Hi thank you for exact solution. Can you tell me about a useful tutorial.

Comment: Also [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) in SO:

Comment: What should be added more to work this expression as a part of other expression as I did't work when use it fully.

Comment: post your string here http://regex101.com , save it to generate a link. Finally post back the link here.

Comment: If I add <span class="movie_info_genres"> before the pattern in demo link, it don't work fine.

Comment: And if we don't know that how many times this need to repeat then?

Comment: Thats why I need repetition pattern

Comment: It works fine alone only. We need to design a pattern for all and it is the part of that.

Comment: Because in the result we can't distinguish between actors and genres. So it is necessary that it should be under span tag.

Comment: not fully resolved but it give an idea that how to go: http://regex101.com/r/iD3xT7/1